# about "sl-vue-tree" . I just want to open the folder

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am a beginner japanese web developer.

I am not good at english sorry.

I am using this component for vue.

https://github.com/holiber/sl-vue-tree

I forked this and I am using it with converting it.

But I have a problem.

When clicking the toggle to open the folder.

That row would be selected.

I just want to open not to select it.

Are there any idea?

When clicking the toggle , emitNodeClick function wasn't called.

So it means the row would be selected in this function.

But it is hard to read inside this function.

```
onToggleHandler(event, node) {
        this.updateNode(node.path, { isExpanded: !node.isExpanded });
        this.emitToggle(node, event);
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

Comment: can you share your codes more on jsfiddle, codepen etc...?

Comment: Thank you for a comment and I am sorry that my response is late. I have never used those before. And this happens on original code too. I just changed looks so there is no difference on function's behavior.